# Shoud I Root My Android Phone to Write/Read From SD Card?

Tags: java, android, root

Yesterday, I tried to make some simple apps which can download xml files from website, and put them on /mnt/sdcard/ . And fortunately, I succeeded in doing it. However, just a moment ago, I wondered if it works just because my phone is rooted. So I wonder if it works on un-rooted android phones?

And thank you, I found the answer : 
It will work both rooted an un-rooted phone. It wont be any problem. :)

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't answer my question. My phone is rooted already. So, did it work because I root my phone, what if I install it on un-rooted phone. will it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: No, you shouldn't. Just make sure you add the Write permission in your msnifest (and I think you already did).

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't need to borrow another device to test it. :D

Comment: @farissyariati Any time. You can borrow mine if you want ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to read/write files to your SD card without any issues.

> Android supports also access to the SD card, all files and directories
>   on the SD are read and writable for all applications.

[This](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidFileSystem/article.html) tutorial contains more information.

Answer (score 1):

Not needed.
Add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside Manifest tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```